# external style sheet issues at time of codeigniter application development

Tags: css, codeigniter

When i am working in codeigniter using xampp in windows pc.After some time changes made in external style sheet will not reflect in web page.But after long time(after restarting) changes will be reflected how to solve this problem?

Comment: you have to disable caching

Comment: Did you set your base url in config.php

Comment: also clear browsing data when changes does not reflect.. shortcut for chrome (ctrl+shift+del)..